# Boot Device Not Found

Tags: system-installation

I went through the instructions for installing ubuntu server on a windows 10 machine and ended up with: `Boot Device Not Found Please Install an operating sytem on your hard disk.` Couple of steps in the install that were not clear:

- The whole partitioning thing generally. I freed up space in Window Disk Manager, but then the install wasn't clearly letting me chose that space.
- The step with GRUB near the end of the install was already telling me that there is no other OS.

Now what?. I now have an unusable machine.

Comment: In your BIOS, is your disk set to RAID, or something else? Did you choose `erase and install` during the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Boot a live USB Ubuntu distro (with a GUI), and try the boot-repair tool:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

You can also burn the tool as a live USB, which might be easier. (Search for boot-repair-disk.)

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem two days ago when i installed ubuntu on windows 10 machine.

First change your boot mode to UEFI.

Second Set first boot device to HardDisk.

And if still doent work it seems like partition in which ubuntu you have installed is not marked as boot so you need to create live usb/cd of Ubuntu and with that live usb/cd choose the option try ubuntu and check there is partitions are available in which you have installed ubuntu using gparted (I dont know gparted is available in try ubuntu i have used elementry so it is availble in that) mark that partition as boot and reboot.